# Can't assign value to JQuery Selct2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I just read a lot of forums to get a idea to how to assign a value to select2. But non of codes worked for me...

Here is my HTML

```
  <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="drpSearchSubjCode">
   </select>
```

I initialize select2 in jquery like this

```
$(".select2").select2();
```

I tried below code to assign value to select2

> Try 1

```
var subjId = 1;
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').select2("val", subjId);
```

> Try 2

```
var subjId = 1;
$("#drpSearchSubjCode").select2().select2("val", subjId);
```

> Try 3

```
var subjId = 1;
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').val(subjId).trigger('change');
```

> Try 4

```
var subjId = 1;
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').select2('data', { id: subjId, a_key: 'My Data' });
```

> Try 5

```
var subjId = 1;
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').val(subjId);
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').trigger('change');
```

> Try 6

```
var subjId = 1;
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').select2('data', { id: subjId, text: "Hello!" });
```

Non of above above codes worked for me... Can anyone help me out to find, where the issue is?

Comment: are all of these commands within the `$(document).ready(function() {});`?

Comment: No. Only initialization done in document ready. others (TRY1, TRY2 etc...) are in outside function.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items):

```
var data = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Hello!'
};
var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

And for selecting:

```
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').val('optionvalue').trigger('change');
```

```js
$('#drpSearchSubjCode').select2();

$('#add').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Hello' + $('#drpSearchSubjCode option').length + '!'
    };

    var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
    $('#drpSearchSubjCode').append(newOption).trigger('change');
})
$('#sel').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#drpSearchSubjCode').val('AL').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="drpSearchSubjCode">
    <option></option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<button id="add">Add new option</button>
<button id="sel">Select option</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply gaetanoM. When use above code, it will create a new element and and append to existing elements. What I need is, already there are elements. According to some function out put, I need to set select2 value which the element is already there.

Comment: Thank you very much gaetanoM for your help. It's really worth and appreciate your effort to solve the issue. :)